# ServiceStack and Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, servicestack

Can anyone guide me on how to make Angular 2 with TypeScript work on a self hosted ServiceStack service?  I had it running with Angular 1 and Razor but now...I am lost.

Comment: I am using VS2015.  I think I am missing a couple of pieces of the puzzle. I don't think I have all the configuration and project structure set properly...I am really a newbie in all this... The page is rendered (IndexResponse.cshtml) but everything related to an angular component is not working (enclosed custom tag <my-app> in my page.

Comment: Can you [show some code?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Finally got it working.  I did so many things that I can't really tell what exactly fixed it but for sure, not having Gulp installed and the javascript folders and files in the right spot did not help...I have to say that all those node.js, npm, Typescript, gulp, all these json config files and more, it is really confusing...